# How do I add a foreach inside another foreach in this context?

Tags: php

When a user registers on my platform, there's some code that removes invisible characters.

I wanted to go further and add **ucwords** into it. However, I need to have some exceptions, as some words in Portuguese names aren't supposed to be capitalized.

The code has one **if statement** and an **else** one. I don't know how to change the else statement to correspond to the same thing as my **if** statement, because it's already a foreach loop.

```
    $exceptions = array('DAS' => 'das', 'DA' => 'da', 'DE' => 'de', 'DOS' => 'dos', 'DO' => 'do');

    if ( !\is_array( $return ) )
    {
        $return = preg_replace( '/\p{C}+/u', '', $return );
        $return = ucwords( $return );
        foreach ( $exceptions as $exception => $fix )
        {
            $return = str_replace( $exception, $fix, $return );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach( $return as $k => $v )
        {
            $return[ $k ] = preg_replace( '/\p{C}+/u', '', $v );
            $return[ $k ] = ucwords( $v );
            //What do I add below? How do I type another foreach instead this one?
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Would this make sense? If so, why?

```
    else
    {
        foreach( $return as $k => $v )
        {
            $return[ $k ] = preg_replace( '/\p{C}+/u', '', $v );
            $return[ $k ] = ucwords( $v );
            //Does this make sense?
            foreach ( $exceptions as $k => $v )
            {
                $return = str_replace( $k, $v, $return );
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: if it's not an array, turn it into an array like `array($return)`, and then run the rest of your code.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I'm not sure if I get what you mean. Could you show me an example of what the code would turn into? I've also edited the main post with an idea, but I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code between array and non-array are the same, so you can write a single foreach

```php
$return = (array)$return;
foreach ($return as $k => $v) {
    $return[ $k ] = preg_replace( '/\p{C}+/u', '', $v );
    $return[ $k ] = ucwords( $v );
    foreach ( $exceptions as $exception => $fix ) {
            $return[$k] = str_replace( $exception, $fix, $return[$k] );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this is what you'd use a function for

```php
function fix_things($s) {
    $exceptions = array('DAS' => 'das', 'DA' => 'da', 'DE' => 'de', 'DOS' => 'dos', 'DO' => 'do');

    $s = preg_replace( '/\p{C}+/u', '', $s );
    $s = ucwords( $s );
    foreach ( $exceptions as $exception => $fix )
        {
            $s = str_replace( $exception, $fix, $s );
        }
    return $s;
}
```

Then call that function from your main code

```php
if (!\is_array($return)) {
    $return = fix_things($return);
else {
    foreach ($return as $k => $v) {
        $return[$k] = fix_things($v);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but do I replace the entire code with what you wrote? Or only the else part? I'm trying to make sense of it.

Comment: i've added an example with a function, so that you can at least reduce the code you've got

Comment: That looks really neat and logical! I'll test and report back, thanks. If I didn't reduce the code, is this what it would look like? --> https://pastebin.com/5aEZtc2n

Comment: what does "$return = (array)$return;" do in your first block? Is it needed?

Comment: if you didn't reduce the code, it would look like that, yes ... the `$return = (array)$return` is only necessary in the shortened version; it turns `$return` into an array with one element if it's not an array, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: Makes sense now! You've been of great help. Thanks, Jack! :)